# Loop trough and modify JSON response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am making API request to Google Sheets and I receive this response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Hours
            [January] => 1
            [February] => 2
            [March] => 3
            [April] => 4
            [May] => 5
            [June] => 6
            [July] => 7
            [August] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Days
            [January] => 3
            [February] => 5
            [March] => 1
            [April] => 6
            [May] => 3
            [June] => 7
            [July] => 4
            [August] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Weeks
            [January] => 3
            [February] => 5
            [March] => 3
            [April] => 4
            [May] => 0
            [June] => 0
            [July] => 2
            [August] => 6
            [September] => 0
            [October] => 0
            [November] => 1
            [December] => 0
        )

)
```

How could I loop trough and modify this array to something like this so I can use it with HighCharts JS library?

```
series: [{
        title: 'Hours',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 .......]

    }, {
        title: 'Days',
        data: [4, 6, 3, 6, ........]

    }, {
        title: 'Weeks',
        data: [1, 9, 1, 3, ........]

    }, {

       ....

    }]
```

I tried this way:

```
if ($response->status) {
            $rawData = json_decode(json_encode($response->data), true);
        }

        $series = [];

        foreach ($rawData as $index => $rawDatum) {

            if (!isset($rawDatum['Title'])) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($rawDatum as $columnKey => $value) {

                if ($columnKey == 'CvA') {
                    $series[$columnKey]['Title'][] = $value;
                }

                

            }
            
        }
```

What I got as result:

```
Array
(
    [Title] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Hours
                    [1] => Days
                    [2] => Weeks
                )

        )

)
```

Also is there a way to get all names of the months saved in $months array for example without doubles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code will create an array with title and the values for each respective subarray Hours, Days, Weeks.

We will also collect the union of the months in an array named `$months`.

```
$series = [];
$months = [];

foreach ($rawData as $subarray) {
    $title = $subarray['Title'];
    // Remove title key
    unset($subarray['Title']);

    $series[] = [
        'title' => $title,
        'data' => array_values($subarray),
    ];

    // Union operator to keep unique months.
    $months += array_keys($subarray);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($months);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result `$months`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => January
    [1] => February
    [2] => March
    [3] => April
    [4] => May
    [5] => June
    [6] => July
    [7] => August
    [8] => September
    [9] => October
    [10] => November
    [11] => December
)
```

Result `$series`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Hours
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 5
                    [5] => 6
                    [6] => 7
                    [7] => 8
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Days
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 6
                    [4] => 3
                    [5] => 7
                    [6] => 4
                    [7] => 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Weeks
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                    [6] => 2
                    [7] => 6
                    [8] => 0
                    [9] => 0
                    [10] => 1
                    [11] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Its exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Given this data:

```php
$data = [
    [
        'Title' => 'Hours',
        'January' => 1,
        'February' => 2,
        'March' => 3,
        'April' => 4,
        'May' => 5,
        'June' => 6,
        'July' => 7,
        'August' => 8,
    ],
    [
        'Title' => 'Days',
        'January' => 3,
        'February' => 5,
        'March' => 1,
        'April' => 6,
        'May' => 3,
        'June' => 7,
        'July' => 4,
        'August' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'Title' => 'Weeks',
        'January' => 3,
        'February' => 5,
        'March' => 3,
        'April' => 4,
        'May' => 0,
        'June' => 0,
        'July' => 2,
        'August' => 6,
        'September' => 0,
        'October' => 0,
        'November' => 1,
        'December' => 0,
    ]
];
```

You should be able to do this:

```php
// Store everything here
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // Grab the title
    $ret['title'] = $item['Title'];

    // Remove it from the source dataset
    unset($item['Title']);

    // Take the remaining values, join with comma
    $ret['data'] = implode(',', array_values($item));
    
    // Append to main array
    $result[] = $ret;
}
```

You can skip the `implode` if want an actual array

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solves my isue too, but I accepted the other answer because it solved my other isue too!